# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.isValid(I)Z

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to deploy a java web application from eclipse, on a tomcat 9.0.4 server, jdk 1.8 and Postgresql 42.2.7 JDBC connector, and when the executive appears the following exception:

```
    FachadaSesion fachadaSesion = (FachadaSesion) application.getAttribute("fachadaSesion");     
    //System.out.print("\n\n Salida ::> " + Format.formatCalendar (Calendar.getInstance (), 2));

    MiUsuarioVO miUsuarioVO = (MiUsuarioVO)fachada.validarUsuario((String)request.getParameter("usuario"));
    session.setAttribute("usuarioInicioSession", (String)request.getParameter("usuario"));
    String pagina="";
    String idUsuario="0";
    String estadoScroll = "no";


org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP [val_user.jsp] en línea [63]

60:         FachadaSesion fachadaSesion = (FachadaSesion) application.getAttribute("fachadaSesion");     
61:         //System.out.print("\n\n Salida ::> " + Format.formatCalendar (Calendar.getInstance (), 2));
62:                 
63:         MiUsuarioVO miUsuarioVO = (MiUsuarioVO)fachada.validarUsuario((String)request.getParameter("usuario"));
64:         session.setAttribute("usuarioInicioSession", (String)request.getParameter("usuario"));
65:         String pagina="";
66:         String idUsuario="0";


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:593)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at vortalHermesoft.filtro.FiltroSeguridad.doFilter(FiltroSeguridad.java:131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.isValid(I)Z
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:667)
    at org.apache.jsp.val_005fuser_jsp._jspService(val_005fuser_jsp.java:338)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.isValid(I)Z
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:924)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:282)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:364)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2355)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2338)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2067)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
    at co.edu.unipamplona.plataforma.connection.DefinitionConnectionVortal.<init>(DefinitionConnectionVortal.java:39)
    at miVortalHermesoft.bdatos.MiUsuarioDAO.<init>(MiUsuarioDAO.java:28)
    at miVortalHermesoft.fachada.FachadaMiVortal.validarUsuario(FachadaMiVortal.java:36)
    at org.apache.jsp.val_005fuser_jsp._jspService(val_005fuser_jsp.java:208)
    ... 32 more
```

Friends already look on the Internet and says that it is the version of Postgresql that is very old, but I have already downloaded the latest version and it does not work for me either, I do not understand why I still get the same exception, Could it be that someone could do me the favor to help me?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL 42.2.7 JDBC driver library contains no class `org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection`. It means you have some pretty old JDBC driver in the class path of your Tomcat. Check what JDBC drivers are you packaging with your application. Also check if there are any JDBC libraries in the Tomcat directory including subdirectories like `lib`.

Comment: Thank you for your indications, but I already cheked JDBC libraries in the Tomcat directory, but all is Ok, and the problem continue.

Comment: Then tell us in what of your JARs is the class `Jdbc3Connection` contained.

Comment: postgresql-42.2.7.jar contained a package org.postgresql.jdbc3, but when I open the class Jdbc3ConnectionPool apear a message that say "Source not found"

Comment: @andresvelez17: Here you write `Jdbc3ConnectionPool`. But your stacktrace containns reference to `Jdbc3Connection`. In the version 42.2.7 there is no such class. Explain us, in what JAR you have this class. This will show that you are have some very old version in your class path.